# Function arguments fixer

Tags: python

I need a function which can fix other functions arguments to constant values.
For example

```
def a(x, y):
    return x + y

b = fix(a, x=1, y=2)
```

Now b should be a function that receives no parameters an returns 3 each time it is being called.
I'm pretty sure python has something like that build in, but I could not find it.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for. Accepting Ffisegydd's answer since he was first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
>>> import functools
>>>
>>> def a(x, y):
...     return x + y
...
>>> b = functools.partial(a, x=1, y=2)
>>> b()
3
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to return a new `partial` object. *Effectively* it provides you with the same function but one or more of the arguments have been filled with set values.

```
from functools import partial

def a(x, y):
    return x + y

b = partial(a, x=1, y=2)

print(b())
# 3
```

Comment: Technically, `partial` is a type, creating a new callable object, not a function.

Comment: @chepner thanks for the note. I've had a quick look at the docs and modified my answer.